# Twenty four again... solution

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I was trying to solve [Twenty Four, Again](https://open.kattis.com/problems/twentyfour) problem. This basic question here is; given four integers in order, you have to put binary operators ($+,-,\times, \div$) and parentheses to make the result of the expression $=24$. Among all such expressions, find the one which has lowest *grade* (*grade* is counted as $1$ for each pair of parentheses, and $2$ for each inversion to the original ordering. *Please check the linked question for detailed explanation with test cases.*

My (attempted) solution is to test all possible ordering of operators and parentheses. Which is the brute-force approach, hence not that elegant. Does anyone has a better idea?

Comment: "My (attempted) solution is to test all possible ordering of operators and parentheses. " That's hardly an attempt in my opinion.

Comment: @A---B You are correct. I did not write the program yet, as do not even have a proper algorithm

Comment: One solution that's immediately better is to search all orderings of grade 0, then all orderings or grade 1, etc etc. The first ordering you find that results in 24 will by construction be the one with the lowest grade.